# C3JS tooltip remains its position without mouseover behaviour

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

on c3js i need that the tooltip have a disable mouseover behaviour and when i make click on the data point and i've set this option in the chart but i don't get it how work exactly.

this set the position but its not a dynamic position depending of the data point

```
tooltip: {
  position: function (data, width, height, element) {
    return {top: 0, left: 0}
  }
}
```

the chart

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
       xs: {
           'data1': 'x1'    
        },
        columns: [
             ['x1', 10, 20, 30],
            ['data1', 190, 200, 190]

        ],
            types: {
            'data1' : 'area-spline',
        },
        onmouseover: function (d, i) {
           // alert('Hovering over');
        },
        selection:{
            multiple:true
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        position: function (data, width, height, element) {
                return {top: 10, left: 10}
            },
                    show: true
    }
});
```

this tooltip remain its position next to the data point only is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle for the same?

Comment: Yes you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/juanX/tmfr3Lyp)

Comment: but there is no code related to tooltip